# Are jokes, caricatures and the sort appropriate?

Tags: discussion, etiquette

While fun, these kind of posts distort the reputation system; They credit their authors with disproportional rankings, not due to professionalism.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Those are relics from the first, happy weeks of the site and thus an exception from the general rules (this is kind of an element of SE folklore).

They are marked as community wiki, so they give no reputation and do not disturb the reputation system.